# Flickr Search with AngularJS, results won't let me scroll all the way to the top

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, flickr

I was following the tutorial about building a Flickr Search App with AngularJS (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lvGAgul5QT4). I was able to display results on the page, but faced a problem: after displaying all the results I was not able to scroll all the way to the to to my search bar to do another search. What could solve this issue? Thank you in advance!

Here is the code:
index.js

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
```

Flickr Search

```
<md-toolbar>
    <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
        <span class="md-flex">Flickr Search</span>
    </div>
</md-toolbar>

<md-content layout="column" layout-align="center center">
    <div class="app-content">

        <form ng-submit="search()" >
            <div ng-show="!isSearching">
                <md-input-container class="long" flex>
                    <label>Search for</label>
                    <input ng-model="searchTerm">
                </md-input-container>
            </div>

        </form>
        <div ng-if="isSearching">
            <md-progress-circular md-theme="blue" md-mode="indeterminate"></md-progress-circular>
        </div>

        <div id="result">
            <md-card ng-repeat="picture in results.photos.photo | limitTo:2">
                <img ng-src="https://farm{{picture.farm}}.staticflickr.com/{{picture.server}}/{{picture.id}}_{{picture.secret}}_b.jpg" alt="" class="md-card-image">         
                <h3>{{ picture.title }}</h3>
            </md-card>
        </div>
    </div>
</md-content>


<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-aria/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/hammerjs/hammer.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-material/angular-material.min.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

app.js

```
    (function(){
    'use strict';
    angular.module('flickrApp',['ngMaterial'])

    .config(['$mdThemingProvider', function($mdThemingProvider){
        $mdThemingProvider.theme('blue')  
        .primaryPalette('pink')
        .accentPalette('orange');
    }])

    .controller('ListController',['$scope','$http',function($scope,$http){

        $scope.isSearching = false;
        $scope.results = [];

        $scope.search = function(){
            $scope.isSearching = true;
            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: 'https://api.flickr.com/services/rest',
                params: {
                    method: 'flickr.photos.search',
                    api_key: 'e232c1eade905d440cbdf4e176c828c7',
                    text: $scope.searchTerm,
                    format: 'json',
                    nojsoncallback: 1
                }
            })
            .success(function(data){
                console.log(data);

                $scope.results = data;
                $scope.isSearching = false;
            })
            .error(function(error){
                $scope.isSearching = false;
                console.log(error); 
            });
        }
    }])
})();
```

style.css

```
    .app-content{
    width: 100%;   
}

form{
    padding: 10px 30px 20px 25px;   
}

md-input-container > input{
    width: 100%;    
}

md-card{
    margin: 0 30px 25px 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To scroll to a specific location using angular we can use location service and anchorscroll service.

Add Id in html to location you want to scroll.

Sample html

```
<div id="scrollto">
//text
</div>
```

Sample script in angular

```
$location.hash(scrollto);
$anchorScroll();
```

This will add scrollto as param to URL and it will scroll to that location.

Answer (score 0):

Try following a recent tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jp-c6_pxAns
You should be able to scroll anywhere on the page.